# Next.js: statically re-rendering components on Dynamic Routes into Full Route Cache on revalidation

Tags: next.js, generatestaticparams

On the one hand, Next.js has [`generateStaticParams`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params) which results in the corresponding pages statically rendered at build time and put into the [Full Route Cache](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#full-route-cache).

However, the docs say, and I've checked this behavior, that `generateStaticParams` doesn't get called on revalidation.

**So my question is**: is there a way to make pages on Dynamic Routes to be statically rendered and put into the Full Route Cache on revalidation?

I'm new to Next.js, so forgive me if the question is naive.

## Details

### Setup

`app/posts/[id]/page.js`:

```js
export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const posts = await getPosts()

    return posts.data.map(post => ({id: post.id.toString()}))
}

// to see whether Full Route Cache was updated after revalidation
export const dynamicParams = false

export default async function Page({params}) {
    const post = await getPost(params.id)

    // JSX markup
}
```

`app/revalidate/post/route.js`:

```js
export function GET() {
    revalidatePath('/posts/[id]')

    // ...
}
```

### Steps

1. Build the application
2. Visit a post under, e.g., `/posts/2`

   The post page gets served
3. Revalidate
   e.g.,

```bash
    curl http://localhost:3000/revalidate/post
```

4. Visit a post under, e.g., `/posts/2`

   Now, a `404` page is served, which is the expected behavior if `generateStaticParams` wasn't called

Comment: i've same problem